# How would I dual boot Ubuntu as Primary and Mac OS X as secondary on a 32bit PC?

Tags: dual-boot, 12.04, mac, macosx

I'm wanting to install Mac OS-X on my 32bit PC as a secondary boot - is this possible to do on a 32bit PC system? would I need to repair GRUB as well so I can use Ubuntu again as my primary?

I'm trying to install Snow Leopard as my secondary boot and YES IM ON A PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X can be installed on a PC; it is called a osx86.

There are some sites about this:

- [Hackintosh Community Forum - Hackintosh.nl](http://www.hackintosh.nl/forum.php)
- [OSx86 Project | InsanelyMac](http://www.osx86project.org/)

But it would take some time. First install Mac OS X and second Ubuntu (if you succeeded in installing Mac OS X). Then the GRUB2 boot loader should read every boot entry, and automatically let you choose between the two OSes at boot-time. If it doesn't, run this in the Terminal in Ubuntu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo update-grub
```